# Trouble retrieving list values in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

So I have a list with the default title field and a custom number field I named "Hours". I want to be able to display the value of both fields on a page. Displaying them is the easy part, but I am having trouble retrieving them.
I am using this code:

```
 var json =  $.ajax({

        url: "[URL]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle([LIST NAME)/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

    })
```

I can then navigate the JSON to get to the results where it shows the information for each item in the list, but I can only find the "Title" field, not the "Hours" field. Also, I tried it on a separate site and was able to get the "Hours" data, but it showed up with an odd name (`d.results[i].o0ci`). I am not really sure what is going on here, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you should check the internal name of your column, let say that i have this structure on sharepoint:

Title | Hours | Has Free Time

well internally sharepoint tends to change the name of those columns to

Title | Hours | Has_x0020_Free_x0020_Time

or some times if you create the column but you delete it, this might happend:

Title | Hours1 | 0o13

So try this code to see your internal names:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "[URL]/_api/web/lists/getbytitle([LIST NAME)/items",
    type: 'GET',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (data){

        $.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
           console.info(value) // You should see all sharepoint fields so you can check the correct fieldname of hours
           console.info("Title: ", value.Title);
           console.info("Hours: ", value.Hours);
        }

    }
});
```